# Is it possible to be subject to cash withdrawal even if you don't use ATM?

Tags: credit-card, rent, transaction

Some companies offer using credit card for paying rent for an extra fee, or some other big-charge transactions that you might traditionally be required to pay for through ACH, a personal check and/or even loan/financing.

If the fee is X, but my credit card would pay me more than X in cash rewards, is it safe to use my US-issued VISA/MasterCard in the US to pay for such transaction?  Is there a chance that I won't receive my points, or that I'll be charged as if I made a cash withdrawal through an ATM, or a balance transfer?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. I say *probably* because your credit card's terms of service may treat certain purchases (I'm thinking buying traveler's checks off-hand) as cash advances. See also [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/38863/what-kind-of-credit-card-transactions-generally-count-as-a-cash-advance).